# Facebook SDK share on page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

My goal is to share an image and a caption text on a particular Facebook page. From what I was able to figure out the ShareDialog provided in the Facebook SDK does not support sharing on Facebook pages. With the pages API, I was able to achieve this with POST GraphRequest with the following code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", PostInstance.getInstance().postMessage);
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/1821194348110590/feed",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.e("graphResponse", "Done");
                        Log.e("graphResponse", response.toString());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

But this requires publish_actions permission which in turn requires app to be sent on review and this also automatically posts the data without prompting the user to approve. Doesn't this violate Facebook's policy? is there any other way to achieve FB page sharing?

Comment: _“and this also automatically posts the data without promoting the user to approve”_ – of course it posts “automatically,” that’s what the API endpoint is for. Making sure that the user is aware of what content will be posted, is _your_ job. You have to implement this in your app’s flow, _before_ you make the API call that creates the post.

Comment: @Rohail Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @MinaFared Sorry for late reply, we had to send the app on review and get was able to get it working after Facebook authorized us the publish_actions permission, as our flow and views made it clear the user that he will be sharing the data on social media so this was not counted as data being shared automatically (without users knowledge)